# How do I run a function on all pandas columns that end in _DT

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a data cleanup script in Python.  I have a base class with a function called cleanData().  Depending on the dataset returned, there are a number of date fields, all of which end in _DT, but could start with anything (such as SCHEDULED_START_DT, SERVICE_DISRUPT_DT, etc).  This code will support hundreds of reports, so instead of overloading the object and method for each report, I would like to dynamically run a function on every field that ends in _DT and just call the parent method if there is additional cleanup unique to a report.  All this code does is change a UTC epoch timestamp into a readable Local Time Zone.  Following are data sample and code I have:

**sample data**

```
ID         SCHEDULED_START_DT               SERVICE_DISRUPTION_START_DT
0          1597669200                       1597712400
1          1597667496                       None
```

**code snippets**

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import datetime as dt
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd

d = {'ID': [0, 1], 
     'SCHEDULED_START_DT': [1597669200, 1597667496], 
     'SERVICE_DISRUPTION_START_DT' : [1597712400, None]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['SCHEDULED_START_DT'] = df['SCHEDULED_START_DT'].apply(lambda x : dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
df['SERVICE_DISRUPTION_START_DT'] = df['SERVICE_DISRUPTION_START_DT'].apply(lambda x : dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
```

**output from code**

```
ID  SCHEDULED_START_DT          SERVICE_DISRUPTION_START_DT
0   2020-08-17 08:00:00         2020-08-17 20:00:00
1   2020-08-17 07:31:36         NaT
```

I think there is a way to dynamically apply the function on all fields ending in _DT without looping and logic constructs.  I have seen some problems that are kind of like this, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Pete

Answer (score 2):

`list(df.columns)` wiil return the the column names.

Loop over it and do the thing:

```
for name in list(df.columns):
  if name.endswith('_DT'):
     #your logic goes here
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try this and I am sure it will work.  I am not an experienced Python programmer, so I thought there would be a more efficient way?  Or does python just do this type of loop under the covers?

Comment: @thePetester if you use exclusively pandas function, numpy implementations do the loops in C, making them much faster

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `filter` (to get all columns that end with `'_DT'`) with `update` (to bring those changes back). In this dummy example I'll just add 20.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 5)),
                  columns=['DT', 'foo', 'foo_DT', 'bar_DT', 'start_DT_end'])

df.update(df.filter(regex='_DT$')+20)

print(df)
   DT  foo  foo_DT  bar_DT  start_DT_end
0   9    3      23      21             6
1   9    4      26      27             7
2   5    7      26      26             4
```

---

In your case we can do away with the slow `Series.apply` in favor of `DataFrame.apply(axis=0)`, which will loop over each column Series instead of the rows. But we need to be careful because [`pandas` is inconsistent with the `datetime` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60256108/datetime-timestamp-returns-different-values-in-pandas-apply-and-dataframe-select/60256274#60256274). So to get your exact output, I need to deal with timezones and subtract the difference.

Also there is an issue with `update` when it tries to overwrite `int` columns with `datetime64[ns]`. So we'll instead `concat` the results back.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

my_date = datetime(2020, 2, 17)
my_date_aware = pytz.utc.localize(my_date)
# Seconds of disagreement
offs = datetime.timestamp(my_date) - pd.to_datetime(my_date).timestamp()
#18000.0

# Turn all into `datetime`
df1 = (df.filter(regex='_DT$').apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce', unit='s')
       -pd.Timedelta(offs, unit='s'))

# Join                columns we didn't modify       those we did
df = pd.concat([df[df.columns.difference(df1.columns)], df1], axis=1)

print(df)
#   ID  SCHEDULED_START_DT SERVICE_DISRUPTION_START_DT
#0   0 2020-08-17 08:00:00         2020-08-17 20:00:00
#1   1 2020-08-17 07:31:36                         NaT
```

Comment: how do you implement OP's function with this filter? I tried to avoid looping by building a list comprehension with `.endswith`, but same as your answer, it raises `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

Comment: I get the same error, here is my code:

_df.update(df.filter(regex='_DT$').apply(lambda x : dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x))_

Comment: according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), passing a df to `pd.to_datetime` will assume the columns are `year, month, date` or other components...

Comment: @RichieV @thePetester it's updated with a few nuances of how to handle your exact case. Turns out `update` has issues, so `filter` + `concat` in that case.

Comment: The only thing this does not work for is daylight savings.  If I pass in the following value:
1595514757

The time stamp returned is:
2020-07-23 08:32:37

when it should be:
2020-07-23 09:32:37